# Solved : Laravel Controller not redirecting properly after an axios post

Tags: reactjs, laravel, controller, axios

im trying to redirect after storing some data passed using axios(ReactJS).
the controller is working fine it store data in the DB ,but it wont redirect to the destination i want.

my component code that s work perfectly:

```
    async onSubmitButton(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("objet", this.state.objet);
    formData.append("id_p", this.state.id_p);
    const response = await axios.post("/CreateCDM", formData, {
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
    })
    .catch(err => { 
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({errorMessage: err.message});    
    })
}
```

and this is my controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $dm = new DossierMedical;
    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $dm->objet = $request->objet;
    $dm->analyseRequis = 0;
    $dm->medcine = $id;
    $dm->patient = $request->id_p;

    $dm->save(); //Working , i cant see that in the DB

    $specialite = DB::table('specialites')
        ->where('nom', 'not like', 'Radiologie')
        ->where('nom', 'not like', 'Laboratoir d\'Analyse')
        ->SELECT('*')
        ->GET();

    return view('dossierMedicale.patient.dm' ,
    ['objet' => $request->objet ,
    'id' => $dm->id ,
    'Specialite' => $specialite
    ]);
```

}

the problem is that im not redirecting to the view i want ,and i cant see any server error in the console.

PS : if i post the data using blade.php(without Reactjs) it redirect me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirection should be done in ReactJS instead of Laravel's controller.

Sample in ReactJS:

```js
    onSubmitButton(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("objet", this.state.objet);
      formData.append("id_p", this.state.id_p);

      axios.post("/CreateCDM", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
         // obtain the data return from controller 
         const { objet, id, Specialite } = response.data;

         //perform your redirection to other routes.
         window.location.href = "/other-routes/";
      })
      .catch(err => { 
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({errorMessage: err.message});    
      })
    }
```

Sample in Controller:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $dm = new DossierMedical;
    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $dm->objet = $request->objet;
    $dm->analyseRequis = 0;
    $dm->medcine = $id;
    $dm->patient = $request->id_p;

    $dm->save(); //Working , i cant see that in the DB

    $specialite = DB::table('specialites')
        ->where('nom', 'not like', 'Radiologie')
        ->where('nom', 'not like', 'Laboratoir d\'Analyse')
        ->SELECT('*')
        ->GET();

    return response()->json([
      'objet' => $request->objet ,
      'id' => $dm->id ,
      'Specialite' => $specialite
    ], 200); 
}
```

Comment: I see now , axios is responsible of the redirection . thanks a looot man